# Hello, I was wondering is there any way for use Tinylog with app which is requiring Log4J2 implementation. (adapter or something)

Tags: tinylog

I was wondering is there any way for use Tinylog with app which is requiring Log4J2 implementation. (adapter or something)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use the tinylog 2 API with an Apache Log4j 2 logging back-end. You can do that by using JBoss logging as an adapter between both.

Required dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tinylog</groupId>
    <artifactId>tinylog-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tinylog</groupId>
    <artifactId>tinylog-jboss</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Example Application:

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.tinylog.Logger;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger.info("Greetings from tinylog!");
        LogManager.getLogger().info("Greetings from Apache Log4j 2!");
    }
}
```

Example Log4j configuration (nothing special):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %logger %level: %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Output on my computer:

```
21:01:27.367 [main] Application INFO: Greetings from tinylog!
21:01:27.368 [main] Application INFO: Greetings from Apache Log4j 2!
```